# Attach .pfx certificate to exe file

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, certificate, exe, x509certificate2

I have to deploy a software to n clients that will install a certificate and use it. I don't want to deploy two files (.pfx and exe) just one (.exe that will contain the .pfx).

What i'm doing now is import the certificate from a location.

```
X509Certificate2^ x509 = gcnew X509Certificate2;
x509->Import( "C:\\Tmp\\certficate.pfx" );
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could always embed the certificate data as a resource.

One warning though: if someone gets the executable, they can pull out the PFX file pretty easily.

Are you able to securely distribute the executable?

Here are some rough steps, distilled from: http://www.spikezilla-software.com/blog/?p=24

- Add the PFX to your project. Then click once on the file, and in the Properties window, set the Build Action to Embedded Resource
- Read the embedded PFX file and import the certificate

This is C# but you should be able to translate to C++/CLI pretty easily:

```
var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyFile.pfx");
var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes, "certPassword");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You have spotted a problem, the exe is public so anyone can have it. Then how i can securely distribute the certificate ?

Comment: I really wish I had a good answer for you here.  It might be worth posting a secondary question "How to securely distribute PFX files"

Comment: The most secure way to distribute a private key is to have the user generate one; you distribute the public key for your needs, they generate a private key for their needs, and then your public key can be used to secure sending their public key to you.  If you just want to verify a license key or similar data, they should only need your public key; your private key stays safe on the server used to generate licenses.

Comment: @ThomasS.Trias If the user generates their own key, how does the server know who the client is?  Anybody can download OpenSSL and create a client cert with info in any of the fields, right?

Comment: @jglouie That is correct; you would need some other factor of authentication for key exchange in order to verify the identity of the sender.  Note that this only need be used during key exchange, since identity could be verified by certificate afterwards.  If their private key is not compromised, the old cert could also be used to update the certificate in case of expiration, but I would stick to a second form of authentication.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me once I embedded it.

```
byte[] cert = Properties.Resources.nameOfCertificate;
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2();
x509.Import(cert, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```