# Certificate not copied to output in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, certificate

I have a ASP.NET MVC project. I use a WCF service that requires a cliebnt certificate. In a console app, I add the certificate file to the solution, set it to copy=always and it works just fine with this code:

```
var certPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "CertificateName.pfx");

var address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("endpoint"), new DnsEndpointIdentity("Skoda.SenderWSSecured"));
_client = new SenderServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_ISenderService", address);
_client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
_client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath, "PasswordForTheCertificate");
```

In my ASP.NET MVC solution I have a ASP.NET MVC project and a Class Library. My code for this service is in the Class Library. I added the certificate file to the Class Library project and set it to copy=always. But it does not get copied to the output. I tried setting the type to None/Content but it did not help.

I tried copying the file to the output in a post-build script but it did not help either. When I compile the solution, I see the the file copied to the output dir but when I run my app from Visual Studio it is not in the directory with the assemblys DLL.

Comment: Yeah I ran into this problem (not specifically certificates). The build system only copies files that are needed to the main project. My workaround was to put it as an embedded resource or build all the projects to the same directory.

Comment: See [Attach .pfx certificate to exe file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914429/attach-pfx-certificate-to-exe-file) for embedding the cert. You might be able to use the certificate store too.